# Add auto increment value to custom meta

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a custom meta "code" in my CPT. How can I make it so that it has a number that will auto increment every time the admin publishes a post?

My solution is to add a table in the database that is "code". Every time the user publishes a post, it will add 1 to the code table. Then I will use a script to append the code from the db to the meta. But it does not seem to add in the db.

Please present alternative/better solutions.

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant codes you have been working with?

Comment: Meta fields are associated to posts in WordPress, which the 'code' meta the 'code' field is associated to?